# Realm nested object can't have the same property name as perant

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have a model named **JVTRoom**
it represents a conversation room, and Its primary key is **roomId**

```
@interface JVTRoom : RLMObject
@property NSString* roomId; // PK
@property JVTInteraction *recentInteraction;
```

There is a model named **JVTInteraction** too, it represents a interaction inside a room.
Every interaction has a property named **roomId** too, so you can reference the room to the interaction.

Server recently added to the room model, a **recentInteraction**:

```
@interface JVTRoom : RLMObject
@property NSString* roomId;
@property JVTInteraction *recentInteraction;
```

Now once I've added this property, the room values are not saved anymore when I call **addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray** with Realm.

**Only the interaction is updated.**
When I remove the interaction property from the room, all the values are saved as expexted.

This is how I make the transaction:

```
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] beginWriteTransaction];
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray:rooms];
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] commitWriteTransaction];
```

As I see it, this is a problem since they both have a string property named roomId, and It causes some problem with indexing.

So my solution for now is adding this to JVTRoom:

```
+ (NSArray *)ignoredProperties
{
    return @[@"recentInteraction"];
}
```

And by ignoring **recentInteraction**, It works.

Have anyone faced this issue and managed to solve it without renaming to property?

Comment: It's unlikely that using the same property names in multiple classes is the problem. Can you share the code in which you call `addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray`?

Comment: Thanks. What value does the `rooms` variable passed to `addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray:` have?

Comment: @bdash I'ts from type NSArray<JVTRoom *> *rooms

Comment: You'll need to share more complete code for anyone to have a chance in figuring out where things are going wrong. Ideally a self-contained piece of code that demonstrates the issue, but if not then at least share the entirety of the code that constructs the objects you pass to `addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray:`. Printing out `rooms` prior to the call, and printing out the objects afterwards which were not updated as you expected would also be helpful.